# Angular Ui Router - Not able to change $state.current.data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am trying to change the value of `$state.current.data` from a controller....but this change is not reflected in .config(function($stateProvider) {}.

```
angular.module("main.loadbalancer", ["ui.bootstrap", "ui.router"]).config(function($stateProvider) {
  return $stateProvider.state("main.loadbalancer", {
    data: { readonly : false },
    url: "device/:id",
    views: {
      "content@": {
        templateUrl: "loadbalancer/loadbalancer.html",
        controller: "LoadBalancerCtrl"
      }
    }
  }).state("main.loadbalancer.vips", {
    url: "/vips",
    templateUrl: "loadbalancer/vip-table.html",
    resolve: {
      isReadonly: function() {
        console.log(this.data.readonly);
          console.log("----------------");
        if (this.data.readonly) { 
          $state.go("main.loadbalancer.readonly");
        }
      }
    },
    controller: "VipListCtrl"
  });
```

---

Controller:

```
angular.module('main.loadbalancer').controller('LoadBalancerCtrl', function($scope, $state, SpinnerSvc, LoadBalancerSvc, Account, DeviceValue) {
  $scope.spinnerOpts = SpinnerSvc.options;
  return (function(load) {
    $scope.$on('deviceNumberUpdated', load);
    return load();
  })(function() {
    return LoadBalancerSvc.getLoadBalancer().then(function(lb) {
      if (lb.ha_status =="secondary") {
        $state.current.data = true;
        console.log($state.current.data);
       $state.go("main.loadbalancer.readonly");
      } else {
        $state.current.data = false;
      }

      Account.id = lb.customer;
      return $scope.loadBalancer = lb;
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but I'd say that it's not possible. But I'd like a better answer.

From AngularJS reference - [Module Loading & Dependencies](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies):

> Configuration blocks - get executed during the provider registrations and configuration phase. Only providers and constants can be injected into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully configured.